# Continuous linear operator and measurability

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider

- a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a filtration $\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$
- separable Hilbert spaces $H$ and $V$
- an $H$-valued stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ with continuous sample paths adapted to $\mathbb{F}$
- A random variable $L : \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(H,V)$, where $\mathcal{L}(H,V)$ is the space of linear continuous (bounded) operators from $H$ to $V$ with the operator norm.

> Show that the process $(Y_t)_{t \geq 0}$, defined as $Y_t (\omega) :=L(\omega)(X_t(\omega))$, is again adapted to $\mathbb{F}$. If necessary one can assume that $L$ takes finitely many values in $\mathcal{L}(H,V)$.

Since for every $\omega \in \Omega$ the operator $L(\omega)$ is continuous, and so are the sample paths of $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, it is easy to see that $(L(X_t))_{t \geq 0}$ also has continuous paths. But why is it also measurable, and, moreover, adapted?

---

One can further introduce
$$
\hat{L} : \Omega \times H \rightarrow V \quad (\omega, h ) \mapsto \hat{L}(\omega, h) := L(\omega)h.
$$
and rewrite
$$
L(\omega)(X_t(\omega)) = \hat{L} (\omega, X_t(\omega)) \quad \forall \omega \in \Omega, \ t \geq 0.
$$
Can this be helpful for the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be true.  Let $H=V=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{F}$ by the filtration generated by a Brownian motion $W$, and $X_t(\omega) = 1$ for all $t,\omega$.  Define $L(\omega)(h) := hW_1(\omega)$.  Then $L(\omega)$ is clearly a continuous linear operator from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $X$ is clearly continuous and adapted, but $Y_t(\omega) = X_t(\omega)W_1(\omega) = W_1(\omega)$ is not adapted to $\mathbb{F}$.

If one desires that $L$ takes finitely many values in $\mathcal L(H,V)$, one could instead define $L(\omega)(h) = h1_{W_1(\omega) > 0}$.

Comment: I have posted a [follow-up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592982) in case you are interested.